# How To Redirect To An External Website Using Webflux endpoints

Tags: spring, api, spring-webflux

```
ServerHttpResponse response;
String google = "www.google.com"
response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create(google));
return response.setComplete();
```

I tried the above code it redirects to localhost:8080/www.google.com

How can I get https://www.google.com without localhost part?

Trying with spring webflux

Thanks

Comment: What is `response` or do we have to guess what object type it is? Please put some effort in if you expect sommeone to put effort in answering.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am sorry for that. I am fixing my question now

Comment: your code doesn't compile

Comment: use https:// in the google url..

Answer (score 0):

How about

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect
or permanentRedirect

```
temporaryRedirect(URI.create("url").build()
```